# Удалить из строки определенное значение sql

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql, mysql

Есть выборка

```
SELECT * FROM `alias` WHERE `query` LIKE 'product_id=%' AND `keyword` like '%.html'
```

Как мне удалить из всех строк в столбце `keyword` окончание  '.html'

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться функциями SUBSTRING и CHAR_LENGTH.

```
SELECT col, SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(col) - 2) AS col_trimmed
FROM tbl
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6080738

Answer (score 0):

Если этого текста нет в других местах строки, то можно так:

```
update `alias` 
set keyword = replace(keyword,'.html','')
WHERE `query` LIKE 'product_id=%' AND `keyword` like '%.html'
```